# jquery ajax return function not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to do a simple ajax request with jquery, and do something based on the return value. The problem is, the ajax request works fine, but the function checking the return data doesn't seem to work on the if "data.result == 1"

It returns fine and the ajax request succeeds (database entry is removed properly), the problem is the checking of the result.

The PHP inside the ajax request:

```
if($_POST && isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && $_SESSION['user_id'] != 0)
{
  if ($user->delete_user_notification($_POST['note_id']))
  {
    echo json_encode(array("result" => 1));
    return true;
  }
}
```

The jquery js:

```
  $('.delete_notification').click(function()
  {
    event.preventDefault();
    var note_id = $(this).data('note-id');

    $.post('/includes/ajax/delete-notification.php', {'note_id':note_id},
    function(data)
    {
      if (data.result == 1)
      {
        alert(note_id);
        $('#note-' + note_id).remove();
      }
    });
  });
```

I've checked what "data" returns and it is correct:

```
{"result":1}
```

Comment: If you don't see the `alert()` then either your PHP `if` condition did not hit or you should check the console for errors as the AJAX request has likely failed

Comment: The ajax request succeeds, as the database entry is removed, the if (data.result == 1) seems to be where it fails

Comment: If you `console.log(data)` what do you see?

Comment: `$.post('...',{...},function(){...}, 'json');` or parse your data: `var data = JSON.parse(data);`